# WebApp: How do I call a new function on the server after the previous has finishes (Callback)?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have been trying for hours now to code a simple AppsScript.
When a function on a WebApp server has successfully finished, I want to send the results back to my client (index.html) and call the next function on the server.
For some reason, I cannot call a new server function from within my callback function. The first callback is executed - Alert "Callback1" is shown -  but the new server function `createSheetsLogfile(selectedLabel)` is not called after.
What am I doing wrong? Is it not possible to call a function on the server from within a callback function?

Thank you very much for your help!
Best wishes, Ben

**index.html**

```
<button onclick="archiveSBEmails()">Start archiving</button>

<script>
var selectedLabel = "";

function archiveSBEmails(){
    selectedLabel = "Testlabel_1";
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callbackFolderCreated).createFolder(selectedLabel);
 } 
       
function callbackFolderCreated(){
     alert("Callback1");
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callbackLogfileCreated).createSheetsLogfile(selectedLabel);      
}


function callbackLogfileCreated(logfileURL){
    alert("Callback2");
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(callbackBackupCompleted).BackupGmailToDrive(selectedLabel);     
}     


function callbackBackupCompleted(){
/...
 }


</script>
```

**code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index')
            .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME);
}

function createFolder(selectedLabel){  
  //function is called from index.html
  // some code ...
    return true;
}

function createSheetsLogfile(selectedLabel){
  //function is called from index.html
  //some code...
  return logfileURL;
}

function BackupGmailToDrive(selectedLabel){
  //function is called from index.html
  //some code..
  return true;
}
```

Comment: You can issue another google.script.run inside of your withSuccessHandler

Comment: Since `logfileURL` is undefined in your example `createSheetsLogfile` is failing.  Try just returning a string.

Comment: @TheWizEd Thanks for your answer. It led me to the problem. I declared and initialized a global variable earlier  in the code which was then reset to "" again everytime code.gs was called.

Comment: @MiMi Thank you, too. This will make my code cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

I declared and initialized a global variable outside of any function earlier in the code which was then reset to "" again everytime a function in code.gs was called.
To solve the problem, I deleted the global variable and introduced another parameter to be handed over to the functions where needed.

Comment: For completeness, please show your solution in the answer.